# Syntax highlighting for llvm c++ api in clion

Tags: c++, syntax-highlighting, clion, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

Right now I'm quite extensively using the C++-Api for LLVM IR. I'm using CLion as my IDE and im building and linking the project via a Makefile.

The includes look like the following

```
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Constants.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Type.h"
```

The problem now is that I don't have any syntax highlighting for the things coming from the llvm headers. How do I enable that.

Comment: CLion has poor support for Makefiles. It's probably not realizing where exactly the imports come from, and thus it cannot make assumptions about types which come from these headers. I personally develop using CMake which CLion has excellent support for.

Comment: Ah okay thank you. I will give it a try!